# Mercurial merge strategy per file type

Tags: mercurial, merge

All:

I want to use kdiff to merge all files with a certain suffix (say *.c, *.h) and I want to do two things (turn off premerge and use internal:other) for all files with another suffix (say *.mdl). The purpose of this is to allow me to employ a type of 'clobber merge' for a specific file type (ie: un-mergable files like configurations, auto-generated C, models, etc..)

In my .hgrc I've tried:

```
[merge-tools]
kdiff3=
clobbermerge=internal:other
clobbermerge.premerge = False

[merge-patterns]
**.c = kdiff3
**.h = kdiff3
**.mdl = clobbermerge
```

but it still triggers kdiff3 for all files. Thoughts?

An extension of this would be to perform a 'clobber merge' on a directory - but once the syntax is clear for a file suffix, the dir should be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge tools can use any executable file.  To set up a merge tool which always overwrites `$base` with `$other`, you can use the following:

```
[merge-tools]
clobbermerge.priority = 100
clobbermerge.premerge = False
clobbermerge.args = $other $output
clobbermerge.executable = <copy executable>
```

When using this strategy on Windows, there is one problem.  You cannot simply replace `<copy executable>` with the `copy` shell command.   For some reason, Mercurial fails to find shell commands in this context.  I have not tried this on *nix.

To work around this problem, you can create a distribute a batch file that performs the copy.  It simply needs to run: `copy %1 %2`.  Once placed on your PATH, you can set `clobbermerge.executable=clobber.bat`.

If you have kdiff3 installed (comes with TortoiseHg on Windows), you can get the same results without the external batch file using a configuration like this:

```
[merge-tools]
clobbermerge.priority = 100
clobbermerge.premerge = False
clobbermerge.args = --auto $base $other $other -o $output
clobbermerge.executable = kdiff3
```

The key to this configuration is the `args` field:

- `--auto`: tells kdiff3 not to open the GUI if there are no conflicts
- `$base $other $other`: tells kdiff3 to only use `$other`
- `$output`: tells kdiff3 the name of the output file

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Mercurial MergeToolConfiguration page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration), you should put the `interal:other` directly after the match pattern:

```
[merge-patterns]
**.mdl = internal:other
```

Comment: the critical part of this question is that I need to turn off premerge for .mdl files as well as applying the internal:other merge strategy.

Comment: If you use `internal:other`, I suppose nothing will be merged and the `other` file is used? The `internal:other` can only be used directly after the file pattern, so you might need to add a premerge hook? http://www.humbug.in/docs/hgbook/ch10s08.html#sec:hook:preupdate